# Cannot create application icons for IOS7

Tags: ios, ios7, icons

I have the following icon as a resource in my app
[image]

I build the app using SDK 6 and it runs fine on SDK 6 ipads and the icons appear fine their

But when I run it on IOS7, the icons on the iPad screen look like this:
[image]

What is wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: that's going to be a difficult app icon to read once it's on the store mate. Look how it looks on your iphone or ipad. you wont be able to read my voices at all.

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/AppIcons.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH19-SW1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the PNG does not have a transparent background. If it does, apple will apply a black background, ergo hiding the black figure.